# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher

Tags: java, spring, java-14

I am trying to build old spring(Version 2.5) project using JDK 14 but when tomcat server starts it throws the below exception

```
[ERROR,ContextLoader,localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/InEditWeb-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:406)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:296)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)

at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)

at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)

at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:254)

at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:198)

at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5128)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5653)

at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1007)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:983)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)

at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)

at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2019)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'component-scan' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher

at org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler$1.parse(ContextNamespaceHandler.java:65)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1253)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1243)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:489)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:384)

... 26 more
```

It works with JDK 7 and tomcat 7 also throws same exception for JDK 8.
Is there need to Upgrade Spring version? How can I migrate the Spring 2.5 to the version compatible with the JDK 14?

Thanks in advance.

Pooja

Comment: What makes you think that old Spring framework (2007) would work with new Java 14 (2020)?

Comment: You could try to remove the check, if it's a check like `if(javaVersion<XXX||javaVersion>YYY)` and see whether it works then

Comment: Spring 2.5 doesn't work on Java14. You are lucky if it works on 8 (apparently it doesn't). So your current combo isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes it's not working on JDK 8 as well.